# Calling modalDialog from from button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modaldialog i am trying to interact with via a button in slickgrid. This is based on slickgrid example 1. Here is my **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/h1totx87/)**

```
<div id="states" class="modalDialog">
    <div>   
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

        <h2>Modal Box</h2>

        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an onClick subscribe function in my grid.

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e,args) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('states')) {    

    }
});
```

The listener works but i cannot get it to call my modaldialog. I have also tried calling it from the button itself.

```
function reportFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return "<button class='states' data-toggle='modalDialog' data-target='#states'>states</button>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem are resources. Check them and their orders. In jsFiddle you are missing jquery-ui.
I added to html window under the jquery.event.drag source

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and i changed dialog like

```
<div id="states" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

and in js window into your event add .dialog like in [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('states')) {    
    $('#states').dialog();
}
```

and dialog now working fine on click button states.